# Wrapping a Django ModelForm with a Div in Crispy Forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following form:

```
class CreateAssignedTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AssignedTest
        fields = ['due_date']
```

That essentially just takes a date field. I would like to leverage some of teh template I am using's built in form helpers but, as I render this with Crispy forms (below), am having trouble over riding the div. Essentially I would like to give it the id (date picker) as below.

**Current (non assigned html):**

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy}}
    </br>
    <input type='submit' value='Create' class='btn'>
</form>
```

**Attempt at wrapping a DIV (what I would like to achieve):**

```
   <div class="input-group date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">{{ form|crispy}}</input
   </div>
```

My question then is: How does one override the ID (or other div class) of a field in Django before its passed to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [Div layout](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html) to wrap field in a Div:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.layout = Layout( 
    Div('form_field_1', css_class="bigdivs", scc_id="id_val"))
```